# I nicked the tip of the taper on a bottom bracket spindle. Is it still safe?

Tags: safety, bottom-bracket

I had to cut the crank arms off of a bike I'm working on. Used an angle grinder. Despite my efforts to avoid damaging the bottom bracket spindle, I nicked it in three places, all at the tip.

The bearings and surfaces are all dandy. Is it safe to use this with new crank arms?

[image: Inline image]  This is the worst of the three.

Comment: You should *carefully* file down any raised spots around your nicks, so that the new arms seat tightly and don't get hung up on anything.

Comment: Curious - what was wrong that you had to cut the crank arms off but the BB was reusable?  Guessing the Extractor threads were stripped?

Comment: @criggie yeah. I stripped them. I think a gorilla assembled this bike, and forgot the grease in a number of key areas

Answer (score 5):

I'd reuse that spindle. The tips bear the smallest load. A nick near the center of the spindle would be more significant

Answer (score 5):

The percentage of the total area of the tapers that is damaged is very small, so you should be able to re-use the bottom bracket. However, cartridge bottom brackets are quite cheap, so if the bearings are showing wear I'd just replace it.

IF you do re-use it, you'll need to carefully file down any burrs raised by the angle grinder, those will prevent a new crank seating on the taper properly.

Comment: Grease the spindle to avoid the same mishap next time you disassemble. And use a torque wrench if possible. Using cranks with built in extractor bolts is a good alternative to standard bolts. They are available as after-market upgrades, too.